# linux socket accept can't been blocked

Tags: linux, sockets, connection, block

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>

    int main()
    {
    int server_sockfd,client_sockfd;
    int server_len,client_len;
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    struct sockaddr_in client_address;
```

create a new socket

```
    unlink("server_socket");
    server_sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
```

name it

```
    server_address.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_address.sin_port=htons(9734);
    server_len=sizeof(server_address);
    bind(server_sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&server_address,server_len);
```

set block

```
    int flags=fcntl(server_sockfd,F_GETFL,0);
    if(flags&O_NONBLOCK==1){
       printf("NONBLOCK");
    }else{
       printf("BLOCK");
    }
    flags=flags&~O_NONBLOCK;
    fcntl(server_sockfd,F_SETFL,flags);
    if(flags&O_NONBLOCK==1){
       printf("NONBLOCK");
    }else{
       printf("BLOCK");
    }
```

listen

```
    listen(server_sockfd,5);
    while(1){
       char ch;
       printf("server waiting\n");
       client_len=sizeof(client_address);
       client_sockfd=
          accept(server_sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&client_sockfd,&client_len);
```

it is blocked at first time

```
      read(client_sockfd,&ch,1);
      ch++;
      write(client_sockfd,&ch,1);
      close(client_sockfd);
   }
}
```

when the client connected first,I work,but the next won't work

Comment: `client_sockfd=accept` Check the value of client_socket. It could be -1 -> check errno, too. Also check the return value from read()

Comment: The socket will be blocking by default, so there's no need to do the fcntl calls. The `unlink` call is totally unnecessary too. Secondly, you **must** check the return value of `bind` which is likely failing (and `listen`, `socket`, etc too...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mismatch may occurs between `client_address` and `client_sockfd`.

The [man page of accept()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept) says:

```
int accept(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);

The addrlen argument is a value-result argument: the caller must initialize it to
contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed to by addr; on return it
will contain the actual size of the peer address.
```

Try:

```
client_sockfd=
   accept( server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_address, &client_len );
```